# Cassandra and MongoDB minimum system requirements for Windows 10 Pro

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, installation

RAM- 4GB,
PROCESSOR-i3 5010ucpu @2.10 GHz
64 bit OS
can Cassandra and MongoDB be installed in such a laptop? Will it run successfully?

Comment: I wonder how did you install windows 10 pro on this laptop at the first place. I believe you should ask this wuestion in Superuser.

Comment: It is installed and working perfectly.

Comment: I can only speak for MongoDB. It will install, but chances are it will only be good for very low demand development work. Cassandra will be more challenging, and you should not expect much when running both MongoDB and Cassandra in any kind of workload with such an underpowered machine.

Answer (score 2):

The hardware configuration proposed does not meet the minimum requirements. For Cassandra, the [documentation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/hardware.html) requests a minimum of 8GB of RAM and at least 2 cores.

MongoDB's [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/) also states that it will need at least 2 real cores or one multi-core physical CPU. With 4GB in RAM, the WiredTiger will allocate 1.5GB for the cache. Please also note that MongoDB will require changes in BIOS to allow memory interleaving to enable Non-Uniform Access Memory, a.k.a. `NUMA`, such changes will impact the performance of the laptop for other processes.

`Will it run successfully?`

This will depend on the workload expected to be executed; there are [documented](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2014/08/multi-datacenter-cassandra-32-raspberry-pis) examples where Cassandra was installed on a Raspberry Pi array, which since the design it was expected to have slow performance and have a limited amount of data that can be held in the cluster.

If you are looking to have a small sandbox to start using these databases there are other options, MongoDB has a service named [Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas), with a model of a database as a service, it offers a free tier for a 3-node replica and up to 512Mb of storage. For Cassandra there are similar options, AWS offers in the free tier a small cluster of their Managed Cassandra Service ([MCS](https://aws.amazon.com/mcs/)), Datastax is also planning to offer similar services with [Constellation](https://constellation.datastax.com/)